# MySQL get new data

Tags: mysql

How I can get 100 new records everyday from a database comprised of 10,000 rows?

**note : every day new 100 rows not edited**

My current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE DATE(`ModifiedTime`)=CURDATE()) Limit 100
```

Comment: You can't. In 100 days, you will run out of rows

Comment: okay no problem, now how i can show 100 rows every day ?

Comment: Could you give more information about what you mean by `**note : every day new 100 rows not edited**`

Comment: @Seba3 just i need to show 100 rows from the 10.000 rows every day

Comment: @BakirOdeh how often does the database with 10,000 records increase?

Comment: Would it be possible for a record in the 10,000 record database to appear more than once in the first 100 days. @BakirOdeh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How i can show 100 rows every day ?

The additional ")" after the curdate() function was removed to prevent the syntax error.  See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63f95c/2/0)

**Before**

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE DATE(`ModifiedTime`)=CURDATE()) Limit 100
```

**After**

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE DATE(`ModifiedTime`)=CURDATE() Limit 100
```